# Find the Inverse Neighbor Pairs

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

#### Definition

We say a pair of integers \$(a,b)\$, where \$0<a<b<N\$ and \$N\$ is an integer larger than 4, is an inverse neighbor pair respect to \$N\$ if \$ab\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }N)\$ and \$1\le b-a\le\log_2{N}\$. There may be no such pairs respect to some integers \$N\$.

To illustrate the definition, consider \$N=14\$. \$(3,5)\$ is an inverse neighbor pair respect to \$N\$ because \$3\times 5=15\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }14)\$ and \$1\le 5-3=2\le\log_2{14}\approx 3.807\$. Another pair is \$(9,11)\$.

On the other hand, consider \$N=50\$. \$(13,27)\$ is not an inverse neighbor pair because although \$13\times 27=351\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }50)\$, their distance \$27-13=14\$ is too large to be "neighbors". In fact, there are no inverse neighbor pairs respect to this \$N\$, since there are no such pairs that both \$ab\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }50)\$ and \$1\le b-a\le\log_2{50}\approx 5.643\$ can be fulfilled.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function, that given an integer input \$N>4\$, outputs or returns all inverse neighbor pairs respect to \$N\$ without duplicate. You may output them in any reasonable format that can be clearly interpreted as distinct pairs by a human, e.g. two numbers per line, or a list of lists, etc.

The algorithm you use must in theory vaild for all integers \$N>4\$, although practically your program/function may fail or timeout for too large values.

#### Sample I/O

For inputs without any inverse neighbor pairs, the word `empty` in the output column means empty output, not the word "empty" literally.

```
Input  -> Output
5      -> (2,3)
14     -> (3,5), (9,11)
50     -> empty
341    -> (18,19), (35,39), (80,81), (159,163), (178,182), (260,261), (302,306), (322,323)
999    -> (97,103), (118,127), (280,289), (356,362), (637,643), (710,719), (872,881), (896,902)
1729   -> empty
65536  -> (9957,9965), (15897,15913), (16855,16871), (22803,22811), (42725,42733), (48665,48681), (49623,49639), (55571,55579)
65537  -> (2880,2890), (4079,4081), (10398,10406), (11541,11556), (11974,11981), (13237,13249), (20393,20407), (26302,26305), (39232,39235), (45130,45144), (52288,52300), (53556,53563), (53981,53996), (55131,55139), (61456,61458), (62647,62657)
524287 -> (1023,1025), (5113,5127), (59702,59707), (82895,82898), (96951,96961), (105451,105458), (150800,150809), (187411,187423), (192609,192627), (331660,331678), (336864,336876), (373478,373487), (418829,418836), (427326,427336), (441389,441392), (464580,464585), (519160,519174), (523262,523264)
```

#### Winning Condition

This is a code-golf challenge, so shortest valid submission of each language wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden by default.

Comment: Nice challenge! Do the neighbor pairs have a practical use somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to @KevinCruijssen and @Grimmy for the fix and inspiration from Kevin's now deleted answer*

*-1 byte further thanks to @Grimmy*

```
L.ÆʒRÆo@}ʒPI%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR@9w26lJQYfb8h1qT00K8FT9/98UAA)

---

## Explanation

```
L.Æ                    - Combinations of [1..N] with 2 elements
    ʒ     }            - Filter this when ...
     RÆo               - 2^(The difference of each pair) is... 
        @              - <= the input
           ʒPI%        - Then filter this list further where the product modulo input is 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `í` be `R`? You want to swap the pair `[a,b]` to `[b,a]` before using the reduce-by-subtraction, not a pair like `[10,12]` to `[01,21]`. ;)

Comment: Btw, our answers are the same now, so I'll delete it. I tbh hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine, otherwise I would have suggested it as a golf.

Comment: Yeah you're right.. I'll change `í` to `R` thanks @Grimmy and @KevinCruijssen

Comment: `.Æ` defaults to 2 (similar to other list operators: `ι`, `ã`, ...), so you can drop the `2` for a 13: [TIO](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR@9w26lJQYfb8h1qT00K8FT9/9/YxBAA)

Comment: Interesting, thanks @Grimmy didn't know that will definitely come in handy :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒcðIḢ2*>¬ȧ⁸P%⁼1ðƇ
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer which yields a list of pairs.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//xZJjw7BJ4biiMio@wqzIp@KBuFAl4oG8McOwxof///8zNDE)**

#### How?

*not updated for less-than-or-equal...*

```
ŒcðIḢ2*<ȧ⁸P%⁼1ðƇ - Link: integer, n
Œc               - unordered pairs (of implicit range [1..n])
               Ƈ - filter keep those for which:
  ð           ð  - ...this dyadic chain, f(pair,n), is non-zero:
   I             -   deltas       [a,b] -> [b-a]
    Ḣ            -   head                   b-a
     2*          -   2 raised to         2^(b-a)
       <         -   is less than (n)    2^(b-a)<n  == b-a<log(n,2)
         ⁸       -   chain's left argument, the pair
        ȧ        -   logical AND           [a,b]    or  0
          P      -   product                a×b         0
           %     -   modulo (n)            (a×b)%n      0
            ⁼1   -   equals one?           (a×b)%n==1   0
```

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto the OP does have <= !

Comment: @RGS Yes it does, but I have little knowledge in Jelly and I don't know whether there are <= operators in Jelly

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto there aren’t. One option would be to do `>¬` (greater than, not), but there may be a golfier option.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto thanks fixed code

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
:2XN!tpG\1=yd|WG>>Z)
```

The output is a 2-row matrix where each column is a pair.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38oowk@xpMA9xtC2MqUm3N3OLkrz/39LS0sA)

#### How it works

Consider input `5` as an example.

```
:     % Implicit input: N. Range [1 2 ... N]
      % STACK: [1 2 ... N]
2XN   % Combinations of 2 elements, as rows in a 2-column matrix
      % STACK: [1 2;
                1 3;
                ···;
                4 5]
!     % Transpose. Each combination is now a column in a 2-row matrix
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
tp    % Duplicate. Product of each column
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [2  3  4  5  6  8 10 12 15 20]
G\    % Modulo N
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [2 3 4 0 1 3 0 2 0 0]
1=    % Equal to 1?
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
y     % Push another copy of the 2-row matrix
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
               [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
d|    % Absolute difference between the two rows
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
               [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1]
W     % 2 raised to that
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
               [2  4  8 16  2  4  8  2  4  2]
G>    % Greater than N? (**)
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
               [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
>     % Greater than. This gives true for entries that are true in (*)
      % and false in (**)
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4;
                2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5]
               [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
Z)    % Use as a logical index into the columns of the 2-row matrix
      % STACK: [2;
                3]
      % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <s>86</s> 79 bytes

```
read*,n
print*,((pack([i,j],mod(i*j,n)==1.and.2.**(j-i)<=n),j=i+1,n),i=1,n)
end
```

*-7 bytes thanks to @DeathIncarnate*

Yes, I still write Fortran in 2020. Here I'm reading an implicit integer n and looping over i and j (a and b would be implicitly reals). An array (i, j) is masked using the intrinsic pack().

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCoAwDEDRvSdJYyxUHc1JxKFYlVRMpXj/qjj9B3/L5S5B2337UWtZQ0RScxXRGwngCssBk1Ca6cwRBBOpZfYuaHSdQ4TUih1ZLSWWxr@XhL@YVWOt/eAf)

Comment: You don't need to use the old array syntax and real(j-i,8) is equivalent to dble in Gfortran. 82 Bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDEDRnZM4xiAFGOuTVAwpTpBDa6KI@6etmP4bfjrrVYMNe7rRWo1BkKwrVe1CAihhO@CplFf6nAKKmcwx@zGYjBOivN4R8qDuweYos/b@N5DyP100aW1e/Bc "Fortran (GFortran) – Try It Online")

Comment: In fact, you don't need to make it a real at all, you can just make the 2 real with a decimal point. 79 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCoAwDEDRvSdJYyxUHc1JxKFYlVRMpXj/qjj9B3/L5S5B2337UWtZQ0RScxXRGwngCssBk1Ca6cwRBBOpZfYuaHSdQ4TUih1ZLSWWxr@XhL@YVWOt/eAf "Fortran (GFortran) – Try It Online")

Comment: @DeathIncarnate Thanks, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>61 59</s>  57 bytes

```javascript
n=>{for(a=b=n;a=a||--b;)--a*b%n-1|2**(b-a)>n||print(a,b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCoMwEETv/Yo9tJBItlSrtCGst177A6XgRhDtYStWvBi/PQ14GYY3vPnwwr92GsYZl3vsKArVa/edFJMncUwcAqJ3GpEzfxLMQ5FlyiPrWkIYp0FmxcbrLbpXZSAvDVQXA9cyN2CtTeRW2PfhnD4f3PZKgGpYYRebJxAcV9ka7aBTknIfUtl0/AM)

The way the `for` loop is written, we have \$b=N\$ during the first \$N\$ iterations and we have \$a=0\$ before \$b\$ is decremented. But in both cases, it implies \$ab\equiv 0\pmod N\$, so the corresponding pairs are rejected anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 56 bytes

```javascript
x=>{for(y=x;i=--y;)for(z=x;z>>=1;)y*++i%x-1||print(y,i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7dCoIwHMXvfYo/QbDlDLf24RjzEXqB6EIiYyJOpohaPbstuunm/DgfF6eppmq4BdeP2VRsVXsPo735bvDt/dj6h0lqu822fNY@oMXOxtksWwz@2jXatSwtNXg5pKnbzxl9vfrguhEtxOH3FleApipAA76GiyBAOQGRE2BCEjhxSkBrHWPFokohTvIHFWeMsyKSSqUUo7HQXOeSifyK4ZnA30u0O4PdEWiwSaBGX7y3Dw)

This \$O(n\log{n})\$ algorithm works practically up to \$N\approx2^{26.5}\approx9.49\times10^7\$.

This was 67 bytes and was originally for my test case verifications only, and then I saw Arnauld's 57 bytes. Inspired by his solution, I checked whether I can golf the loops while keeping \$O(n\log{n})\$ complexity, and here it is.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>76</s> 71 bytes

```
lambda N:[(a,b)for a in range(N)for b in range(a)if(1<<a-b)-N<a*b%N==1]
```

Thanks, Jitse, for saving me 5 bytes after some discussion.

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##RYzRCoMgGEbv9xQSDHT8wtSsGblH8AVaF8pyCzaL8mZEz@5WN/suvosD54yf@ByCSF7f0su@3d0iUzXYgiN@mJBFfUCTDY8Omx24P7Ck95jVtaWOUFPbkzsarVmbYjfHWTcSGAOWgzwDlwWInIFSCljJFRRSimL/EiTP@aVsD1s@bPndbyoq2uqAfhunPkTssyWsiF7R4nEga0bSFw), where I'm not running the larger test cases because it times out

Comment: @Jitse why does your //N work? Because //N divides by N and rounds down, isn't that too permissive?

Comment: @Jitse what I mean is that if `x = N+1` then `x//N<=1` passes the test but `x<=N` doesn't. Do you get what I am saying?

Comment: @Jitse imagine `N = 11`, `a = 10`, `b = 6`. Then `2^(10-6) // 11 = 16//11 = 1` but it is not true that `2^4 <= 11`. Thus the inequality seems too loose.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->n{(r=*1...n).product(r).select{|a,b|b>a&&a*b%n==1&&n>=1<<b-a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoMgEADQq7iw@MlAO62mIRm4iHEBVleWGqqJDXB2@p4/7C8vKnPtQu1Vi0II14jNf17HtNe@Ed95nac9RAM2Wm0YM629OKWQMacVElluUspDD9hBf4NHhyClBHze5SjeZgvxjKUmOomqguuiIlqGcyQqryn/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＮθＦθＦιＦ‹›Ｘ²⁻ικθ⁼¹﹪×ικθＩ⟦⟦κι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo7C8IwFIV3f8UdbyAOFurSUUSEWjq4lQ6xRrw0TcxLf368Sg@cB5xveqowOWVKOdtXTl1ebjqgF83m4QLwgH/T2q2OEU9Bq8RU7z6clYQL2RyRJMxCSPDso8/KRNzx5@7ZOLzSolfkR7CgD2QTHlRMOAyzBBpHIZpSqnpftm/zBQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `N`.

```
ＦθＦι
```

Loop `0 <= a < b < N`. (`a=0` can never be a solution, so it doesn't hurt to include it.)

```
Ｆ‹›Ｘ²⁻ικθ⁼¹﹪×ικθ
```

Check whether `2**(b-a)<=N` and `a*b%N==1`.

```
Ｉ⟦⟦κι
```

If so then output `a` and `b`, on separate lines, with each pair double-spaced.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -lm, 76 bytes

A port of [my JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198874/58563).

```c
a,b;f(n){for(a=b=n;a=a?a:--b;)--a*b%n-1|pow(2,b-a)>n||printf("%d,%d ",a,b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBCoMwFATQfU/xCQhJ8YO2utCQ9gaeoJsfJSJoFFvqQr160xQqLtzN8IYpsS5L5yjU0nArZtOPnJRWVpKiO@WIWgpEOuvAYrwM/cQvoUYSN7ssw9jYl@EsqMKgAhb6FyFX9@6bCjpqLBcwnwD@MwBWqBQgByYk/Hoq5M7sYQsVJzvHyYHTaOc0OvA1iTf28cBZlm3so@fVfUrTUv10ODlsuy8)

Comment: Hmm... There's got to be some way to use `1 << b-a` rather than `pow(2, b-a)`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne That would limit the maximum difference between \$a\$ and \$b\$ to \$31\$, which IMO is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), <strike>140</strike> <strike>94</strike> 90 bytes

```
define f(n){for(a=2;a<n;a=a+1){for(d=1;2^d<=n;d++){if(a*(a+d)%n==1){print" ",a,",",a+d}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5RC4IwFIXf76@4DIItDdxymsz1SyJYzdEgl4gSIf52G@ulc@E8nO8cuLf7ttnO@dCho4Et7jVSo4UybVBGm4z/Iqu5Elfb6qBslrHFO2r21GSW7YLWsTSMPkwESW5yEi@SNWqD98M/O6Q@DPOkx85YyhgugFFpgonkSPBwRpJyO/f9B3X8JzH2VyaXQBSssEngJcgCjiWHpmmA16KBSspjlbwGKUpxqqH4Ag)

Function f() takes the number as input, writes its output to stdout, and returns 0, which should be ignored.  The test wrapeper in the TIO needs a special marker for end-of-file, as it otherwise keeps trying to read

Having looked at another answer, I saw I could do \$2^{d}\le{n}\$ instead of \$d\le\log_2{n}\$  -46, including the +2 for -l.

I was amazed to find it turned into a one-liner.

I then realized I had two unneeded pairs of parentheses.  -4.

I have also realized that I allow b>n, but it apparently doesn't hit in the test cases.

Edit: it turns out with \$0<a<N<b\$, there can't be a hit unless \${{b-a}\over2}\ge\sqrt{N-1}\$  Combining with the neighbor requirement of \$b-a\le\log_2{N}\$ we get \$2\sqrt{N-1} \le \log_2{N} \$  This only happens at \$N=1\$, so I'm safe.

### ungolfed:

```
define f(n) {
    for (a=2; a<n; a=a+1) {
        for (d=1; 2^d<=n; d++) {
            if (a*(a+d)%n==1) {
                print " ", a, ",", a+d
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### originally: [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) -l, 138 + 2 = 140 bytes

```
define f(n){
scale=9
m=l(n)/l(2)
scale=0
for(a=2;a<n;a=a+1){c=a+m
if(c>=n)c=n
for(b=a+1;b<c;b=b+1){if(((a*b)%n)==1){print " ",a,",",b
}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RasMwDEXf9RXGMLC3lCVu3My46pfsxXYSZnCckKaMEfrr81xvD5NAQveeC7IupX4YfRzIyCLf4epMGFDBhCHfr4EJ/qfVMM4rMyi0OUdt0Lw0fHd5TeBH5i4YucNYIPswtT07bdE@sAwwZp4tf4ocMQvL6uNGKKGVqWhuC/dcCT4/fBgI83G5bbgOpmeckx1Irt9IcaqcPFwILXp/m6Yvgvn/4vF/MH2PVMMdkoSmBVnDsW1AKQVNJxScpDyeyuxAila8dVB/z8vm53hNh/AD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 46 bytes

```
riJs1ro2CBf{Jp^.-ab2j**g1.<jpdg1.%1==&&}:U_:so
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KNOr2LAo38jZKa3aqyBOTzcxyShLSyvdUM8mqyAFSKka2tqqqdVahcZbFef//29sYqgAAA)

```
ri     # Read as int
Js1    # Store a copy
ro     # Range [1,N]
2CB    # Combinations of length 2
f{     # Filter for
 J     # Duplicate
 p^.-  # i-j
 ab    # |i-j|
 2j**  # 2^|i-j|
 g1.<  # < N
 jpd   # i*j
 g1.%  # (i*j)%N
 1==   # Equal to 1
 &&    # Bitwise and
}
:U_    # Filter out i=j
:so    # Filter for sorted (removing duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 57 bytes

A port of my Python answer

```
f n=[(a,b)|a<-[0..n],b<-[0..a-1],2^(a-b)<=n,1==mod(a*b)n]
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzZaI1EnSbMm0UY32kBPLy9WJwnCStQ1jNUxitNI1E3StLHN0zG0tc3NT9FI1ErSzIv9n5uYmadgq5CSz6WgUFBaElxS5JOnoKJQnJFfDqTSFExxiBua4NJggEPC2MQQh4ylpSUuW8yNLP8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 55 bytes

```perl6
{grep {[*](@^a)%$_==1&&$_>=2**[R-](@a)>=2},(^$_ X ^$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAoTpaK1bDIS5RU1Ul3tbWUE1NJd7O1khLKzpIFyieqAnk1OpoxKnEK0QoAEnN2v/FiZUKekAj0vKLFEx1FAxNdBRMDXQUjE0M/wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>77</s> 64 bytes

```r
function(N)which((o=outer(x<-1:N,x,'-'))>0&2^o<=N&x%o%x%%N==1,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcW7CoAgFADQva9o0e4FhewxGNonODW3SGJLF0LJvzdcznlr6I2sIT8@3fSAwy/ePgKQpZyuF4qRanOiiEEOiPvIp5OMdbwwYoUxZ60SB9YAK3YB1NJcx@a8qJbWGusP)

Returns a matrix with columns `b,a` of all inverse neighbor pairs. Since it creates several `NxN` matrices, this will run out of memory in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 24 bytes

```
fȯ≤¹`^2F-fȯ=1%¹F*fF>´×,ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@3E@kedSw7tTIgzctMFcmwNVQ/tdNNKc7M7tOXwdJ2HOxb////f2MQQAA) Nothing too complicated, just the three filters applied to the list of ordered pairs.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ à2 fÈrÍ§U«1nX×uU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDgMiBmyHLNp1WrMW5Y13VV&input=MTQKLVI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```
n_:>Select[Range@n~Subsets~2,Mod[1##&@@#,n]==1&&2^#[[2]]<=2^#[[1]]n&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbRCoIwFADQXxEGe7pldymxaLIfCCofxy2WzhLyBjmfIn99RefpDD7ew@Bj3/jUmcSXbVWHR2iiO3m@BctzPV3HEMdZwf7ZOhRCWiuAyRiUUp2Fc4poZ/5DIpaUDq@eoxOL6jj14Zd82RHJLLfZuwQsoFzBukDQWgNulP6kLw)

Defined as a [delayed rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) that can be applied to any integer.